# Wiring 2 lights with 2 switches in a double gang box

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, light

I am trying to wire 2 lights, one ceiling and one over my door for my porch. I have 2 switches in a gangbox already as well. This was the previous set up before I redid our porch.

Currently have 3 14/2 cables in my gangbox, 2 14/2 cables in the junction box for the ceiling light, 1 14/2 cable in the outside light.

Is there a proper set up for this, most things I have tried either only turns on one light over the door or blows a fuse in my panel

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the ceiling fan box and the switch box?  You may have wired yourself into a bit of a corner here if you actually have a fan...

Comment: No fan sorry that was a typo, simple light with one black and one white wire inside porch. Same wires on outside light as well. Nothing has been changed in the wiring nor have the lights. This all worked before we did renovations but our electrician got called away back to his normal job. Again 2 14/2 in ceiling box connecting to a ceiling light with one black/white wire. 2 switches in gangbox with 3 14/2 cables and also an outside light with 1 14/2 cable in box hooking to an outside light with a black and white wire on that

Comment: We'll need photos of the insides of the ceiling light and switch boxes anyhow then

Comment: Also, where does power come into this setup at?

Comment: Why is a picture needed? I've explained in detail whats in each area. Gangbox 3 14/2 cables which need to connect to two single pole switches, power supply is in gangbox. Junction box in ceiling has 2 14/2 cables that needs to connect to a single basic overhead one lightbulb  light  with just 1 black and one white wires on it. Outside junction box has 1 14/2 cable that needs to connect to a basic light with one black and one white wires

Comment: @TommyHickey it can be easier to see how the wires are connected if (clear, well-lit) pictures are provided rather than going back and forth in the comments here asking you for more info and more info, especially if your knowledge with lighting circuits is limited.

Answer (score 1):

In the switch box ("gangbox" is not what we call it) One of those 14/2 cables is the hot feed from the panel.

In that box:
All of the bare wires (grounds) get connected together.

All of the white wires (neutrals) get connected together.

The switches are fed from the black wire from the panel.

The switches are then connected to one each of the black wires to the ceiling light and outside respectively.

Good luck and stay safe!

Comment: How does the connections go for the 2 14/2 cables in the ceiling light? I connected all whites together in the switch box I then took the hot wire and added 2 pig tails to it and fed each tail to each switch and the remaining blacks went one each switch as well. With this set up I can get the outside light to turn on. However my issue is if I connect the 2 black wires and 2 white wires in the ceiling and marrete them onto the white and black wire from the light fixture, the light stays on permanently

Comment: Hmmm sounds like one of those cables in the ceiling box is a hot feed. You should test to see which cable is coming from the switch box and use that cable. It could be the other cable was a hot feed for a ceiling fan with a pullchain but if you have a proper switch leg you can use that for the light and cap off the other black wire.